# cURL: Post values needed?

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm using php and curl to get the content of various websites. Some sites require post values. I want to check if the site expect any post values to be sent.

Comment: you can't. this needs to be documented by the site itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, unless sites specifically tell you in their response headers what they are expecting (and they rarely, if ever, do). Best you can do is take a look at returned headers from the request. You cannot automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking here OP. But when creating scripts in cURL to automate interaction with other websites you generally have to investigate manually to find out what parameters need to be passed to get to the information you want...

It'll be a case of using tools such as Source Code View, and the firefox addon which allows you to modify post information (forgotten what its called) to see whats actually happening when you visit the site.

Comment: (forgotten what its called) = (TamperData firefox extension)?